# Upgrading Node.js/Mongo app from Redhat Openshift2 to Openshift3, what's the mongodb URI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, openshift

I think I have node.js and mongoDB successfully installed on my Openshift3 "Starter" Account.

In Openshift2 there used to be a complete MONGODB URL environment variable.  Now there seems to only be a USER and PASSWORD variable.  How do I know the server, port, etc???

Comment: Could [this](https://developers.openshift.com/databases/mongodb.html) be it?

Comment: @Chris G Thanks, but since that post refers to the `rhc` command line interface, not the new `oc` one, I believe those are the older v2 environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenShift (Kubernetes) sets [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables) for all services in your project/namespace in your pods when the pod is created. The environment variables are prefixed with their corresponding service name (the service name is converted to uppercase and dashes are replaced with underscores):

- {SERVICE_NAME}_SERVICE_HOST
- {SERVICE_NAME}_SERVICE_PORT

Your Node.js app will still need to know what you named the the MongoDB database service along with the username/password for the database, so you'll want to set those in environment variables in the Node.js deployment config.

Assuming you named your Node.js service `nodejs-ex`, your database service `mongodb`, your database `sampledb`, your username `user` and password `pass`:

```
$ oc set env dc/nodejs-ex DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME=mongodb \
    MONGODB_DATABASE=sampledb \
    MONGODB_PASSWORD=pass \ 
    MONGODB_USER=user
```

And, somewhere in your app (based on the [Node.js sample app](https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex/blob/64c46cb6ee84d6cdb7e96f54bb7a1b7362bff107/server.js#L13-L34)):

```js
if (process.env.DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME) {
  var mongoServiceName = process.env.DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME.toUpperCase(),
      mongoHost = process.env[mongoServiceName + '_SERVICE_HOST'],
      mongoPort = process.env[mongoServiceName + '_SERVICE_PORT'],
      mongoDatabase = process.env[mongoServiceName + '_DATABASE'],
      mongoPassword = process.env[mongoServiceName + '_PASSWORD']
      mongoUser = process.env[mongoServiceName + '_USER'];

  if (mongoHost && mongoPort && mongoDatabase) {
    mongoURL = 'mongodb://';
    if (mongoUser && mongoPassword) {
      mongoURL += mongoUser + ':' + mongoPassword + '@';
    }
    mongoURL += mongoHost + ':' +  mongoPort + '/' + mongoDatabase;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that long messy demo code and my response was "WTF?"  Was hoping for (and still hoping for) something simpler...  On the bright side, I guess its an opportunity to write a small NPM module.

Comment: Also, this doesn't help if I want to connect from the mongo CLI.

Comment: What do you mean something simpler? Pass the service name to the app and you have access via two env vars. Also where are you trying to connect to the mongo cli from?

Comment: Simpler version: `$ oc set env dc/nodejs-ex MONGODB_URI=mongodb://{username}:{password}@{database_service_name}:27017/{database}`. You don't need to know the IP of your database service. Every service is given a DNS name (DNS name = service name). You can reference services in your namespace/project using their DNS name.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to access the MongoDB CLI, just `oc rsh` into the MongoDB pod and run: `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/$MONGODB_DATABASE -u $MONGODB_USER -p $MONGODB_PASSWORD`.

Comment: Thanks!  For the record, I got a reply from OpenShift including this [link to a course on port forwarding](https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/port-forwarding/) for using a CLI.  Now, any way to use a mongo GUI client?  :-)

Comment: Once you setup port forwarding you should be able to use a local GUI client to connect to your remote database.